# How to display proximity id in Estimote

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I have develop a code for fetching the list of Estimote near by and i want to show the all Beacons info so i use it's property like major,minor,distance, macaddress and proximityUUID. But when i run the application is show the proximity id like

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.proximityUUID];
```

and how to fetch the different id it is macaddress or proximityUUID?

Answer (score 1):

Things like proximity uuid, major or minor you can read from beacon without connecting to it. 
But if you want to read MAC address or temperature (in newest firmware version) you need to be connected to the beacon. 
To do this set yourself (your class) as beacon delegate `self.beacon.delegate = self` then call `[self.beacon connect];` method. Also Implement `-(void)beaconConnectionDidSuccedded` - this method will be called after successful connection to beacon.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTBeacon         *beacon;

.
.
.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

ESTBeaconManager  *beaconManager = [[ESTBeaconManager alloc] init];
beaconManager.delegate = self;

ESTBeaconRegion   *beaconRegion = [[ESTBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:self.beacon.proximityUUID
                                                             major:[self.beacon.major unsignedIntValue]
                                                             minor:[self.beacon.minor unsignedIntValue]
                                                        identifier:@"RegionIdentifier"];
[beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];

.
.
.


cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString];
```